# Accessing cocoa interface builder controller methods

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

So I have an objective-c project that uses a controller class.  This interfaces with interface builder via IBOutlets.

My understanding is that the controller gets initialized by loading the user interface (as it is added to interface builder as an object).  I would then like to use the controller's getter methods to return values that are in the IBOutlet fields.

So, to clarify what I mean with some code, here's my controller interface/implementation:

```
@interface controller : NSObject {
@private
IBOutlet NSTextField *name;
}   
-(NSString*) name;
@end
```

Then, in my implementation, I have:

```
-(NSString*) name
{
    return [name stringValue];
}
```

in a third class, I'd like to be able to write:

```
NSString blahblah = [controller name] and have the value of blahblah assume the value of whatever is in the controller's IBOutlet "name" field.
```

Hopefully this makes sense.  When I try and do it this way I get "Semantic Issue: Method '+name' not found (return type defaults to 'id')"

Why?  Where is the controller object actually substantiated and where, and how do I access it's fields?

Comment: There are more errors here than lines of code - a controller inheriting directly from NSObject, incorrect use of pointers, accessor names obscuring ivar names, incorrect MVC, etc. It would be best to back up and read Apple's "The Objective-C Programming Language" and then move on to a book/tutorial on Cocoa application development.

Answer (score 2):

You have to instantiate the controller by using [[controller alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];

By just using [controller name] you are calling a class method. Also it should be NSString *blahblah

You should read this document:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007594

Comment: So where exactly should I instantiate the controller?  In the app delegate?

Comment: depends on what you are trying to do and where you want to add the view controller into the hierarchy. i would suggest taking alexantd's advice and reading apple's documentation and then a cocoa tutorial